# 422 error lacks Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront

1) I have had my react app hosted in a S3 bucket served by Cloudfront with a custom domain.

2) Then I have my Express API server live on a Lightsail instance with Nginx/PM2.

Now I'm having `422` CORS issue when calling an endpoint from my React. I have tried the following:

1) Add the following CORS rules to the S3 bucket that contains my React app assets:

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

2) Pasted the Nginx config from here https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html to my api's server block:

```
server {
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000
     ...
     ...
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
     ...
     ...
```

3) In my React app's cloudfront distribution's 'Behaviours' page:

- 'Cache Based on Selected Request Headers' -> Whitelist the `Origin` header
- Allowed all http methods...
- Forward all cookies...
- Forward all 'Query String Forwarding and Caching' too...

But still no luck.

I can get some response from running this:
`curl -s -D - -H "Origin: https://app.react.app" https://api.react.app/isOnline`

`curl -i -X OPTIONS https://api.react.app/isOnline` gives me `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` success.

What else can I try...? Appreciate any pointers..

Comment: You can try doing `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;` — that is, append the `always` keyword to your `add_header` directives. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header. Otherwise, if you don’t do that, nginx will only add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to 2xx success responses and 3xx redirects — but not to 4xx errors. That will fix the CORS issue — but the problem will still be that the server’s responding with a 422 error rather than a 200 OK success response.

Comment: You can try making an OPTIONS request with curl, like this: `curl -X OPTIONS [other args] [URL for your Express API endpoint]`. If `https://app.react.app` is the URL for the React app that’s running the frontend code you’re making the request from, then when you test with curl, you don’t want to make the request to `https://app.react.app` — instead you want to make the request to your Express API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker. Doing `curl -i -X [URL for your Express API endpoint]` gives me `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` as expected! But why still `422` and CORS in browser complaining can't read remote resource in my `https://api.react.app/some_endpoint` :(

Comment: Seems like you need to check the server logs on server side of the Express API endpoint server and see what messages it’s logging there which lead to it ending up sending back a 422 response. Is there some reason you can’t access those logs? Or have you already checked those logs and not found anything?

Comment: @sideshowbarker It's working now! The `always` was the ticket. The `422` had nothing to do with CORS issue here(it's a error code I explicitly set, sorry!). If you would edit the question and create an answer for this, I would totally accept it! (Edit: I'm gonna try revert Item 1 and 3 and see if it still works..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header gets included in a `422` error response or other `4xx` response, then you need to append the `always` parameter to your `add_header` directives, like this:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
```

Otherwise, if you don’t do include that `always` parameter, nginx will only add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `2xx` success responses and `3xx` redirects — but not to `4xx` errors. 
See the docs at https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header.

Comment: Your help was much appreciated!